# Dragon Dictation mouse clicks

Tags: mouse, voice-dictation, click

I use a speak recognition program Called Dragon Dictation. When I work I use the program for mouse clicks but I have to say "mouse click" which doesn't seem like a big deal but when you're saying it 100 times a day it would be so much easier to just say "click". Most of the commands I can see in AppleScript code and I can copy and paste it to make my own commands. However, the mouse clicks are not shown for some reason.

**Update:**
Dragon dictation is no longer supported on Mac computers. Here is an alternative for mouse clicks: https://github.com/bobbymay/Dictation-for-macOS

Answer (score 3):

You can just install a command-line utility for clicking and then call it via a Dragon dictate command. the utility can be found here:

https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick

then just make a Dragon shell command like this:

- name: "click"
- Shell script: /usr/local/bin/cliclick c:+0,+0

you can do the same for double-click, but for right-click, and option-click you need to use some AppleScript. Also, check out this project I'm working on: http://voicecode.io which solves all of these problems plus tons more

Answer (score 2):

In [Dragon Dictate 4](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm), as in Dragon NaturallySpeaking on Windows, Nuance doesn't let you access the code behind some commands, such as mouse actions.

As far as I know AppleScript has no command to trigger a mouse click without specifying where it should click. You can use [Extra Suites](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9730/extra-suites) (10 USD) to extend AppleScript's ability and define the following AppleScript:

```
tell application "Extra Suites"
   ES click mouse
end tell
```

Extra Suites has a bunch of other useful commands, e.g. to change the screen resolution or set the sound volume to a specific level.

Example:

```
tell application "Extra Suites"
   ES click mouse with double click
end tell
```

+100 for Ben for his answer, we need such initiatives to unleash the power of voice recognition for desktop users for Mac and Windows (and Linux seriously needs to get some decent speech recognition software).